# PHP While HTML Table

Tags: php, html, sql, while-loop, html-table

I am trying to get my code to display in an HTML table using the `while` loop. However, I can't get my table to display. Is there something wrong with the way I am trying to echo the table out?

```
 <?php


 #-----call includes-----# include('E:/includes/database.php'); 
 include('E:/includes/sendmail.php');

 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
 ini_set('display_errors','on');


 $do = $_REQUEST['do']; 


$queryOrders = "select t2.SlpName As 'Seller', t1.SWW As 'Vendor', t0.DocDate As 'Date',t0.DocTotal As 'Total'
                from twh.dbo.OINV t0
                  inner join twh.dbo.inv1 t1  on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry

         inner join twh.dbo.OSLP t2 on t1.SlpCode = t2.SlpCode
                where t0.DocDate > DATEADD (month, -2, getdate())
                  order by t0.DocTotal desc";

$resultItemData = sqlsrv_query($con, $queryOrders);


    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr><th>Seller</th>";
    echo "<th>Vendor</th>";
    echo "<th>Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Total</th></tr>"
    while($rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultItemData)){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "$resultItemData";
        echo "</td></tr>";
    endwhile;

    }
    echo"</table>";
```

Comment: See answers they pinpoint your syntax issue..  Also would suggest, not doing echo for every line --- that is not needed.  Or use a heredoc.

Answer (score 1):

Modified a little bit. Check this:

```
while($rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultItemData)) :
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $rowItemData[ColumnValue]; //In your code, didn't access the column value earlier 
    echo "</td></tr>";
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a combination of problems at play:

1. First, you open the while with `{`, but close with `endwhile;` - while technically not a problem, it's not consistent - if you open with `{`, it's best practice to close with `}`.
2. Second, you're attempting to echo an entire *array*, which won't work properly.
3. Third, no need to put the value inside of quotes: `echo "$resultItemData";` could simply be `echo $resultItemData`.
4. Fourth, you're attempting to echo `$resultItemData`, which is a resource, not the row data.  You want to echo `$rowItemData` values.
5. And finally, you'll likely want the results in an associative array, rather than a numerically-indexed array, so you might consider using `sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultItemData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`.

Below is your code, revised to work, and follow a bit better practices:

```
// columns: 'Seller',Vendor, 'Date', 'Total'
while( $rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultItemData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<td>$rowItemData['Seller']</td>";
    echo "<td>$rowItemData['Vendor']</td>";
    echo "<td>$rowItemData['Date']</td>";
    echo "<td>$rowItemData['Total']</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Good explanation @cale_b.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through your full code, but I can see wrong syntax for while

```
while($rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultItemData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Seller']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Vendor']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Total']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

or

```
while($rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultItemData)) :
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Seller']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Vendor']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$resultItemData['Total']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
endwhile;
```

Update: 
still you can optimize the code, I just gave sample working

Comment: Yes but you did not point out the issue with trying to echo out a query handle.

Comment: `echo $resultItemData;` is suspicious to me. Which results *..Catchable fatal error: Object of class sqlsrv_result could not be converted to string*

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the indexes of the array `$rowitemdata.`

**For example:**

```
echo"<tr><td>".$rowitemdata['Vendor']."
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your query actually produces a result, because you don't check that it does:

```
$resultItemData = sqlsrv_query($con, $queryOrders);

$header = <<<HEREDOC
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <th>Seller</th>
  <th>Vendor</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Total</th>
</tr>
HEREDOC;

echo $header;

while($rowItemData = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultItemData)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$rowItemData['Seller']}</td>
            <td>{$rowItemData['Vendor']}</td>
            <td>{$rowItemData['Date']}</td>
            <td>{$rowItemData['Total']}</td>
          </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

To actually check that the query works, you might want to do this instead.  This is just to debug/illustrate error checking for the query execution.  You wouldn't want to output an error to the screen, but rather log it.  You probably want to just output the table header/footer and skip the while/loop entirely.

```
$resultItemData = sqlsrv_query($con, $queryOrders);
if (resultItemData === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```